# How do I get line break in textBlock working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I somehow can't seem to get a line break in my TextBlock.

`TextWrapping="Wrap"` doesn't work. Also anything else such as `TextTrimming` doesn't affect my TextBlock at all. I assume an other control is blocking? Talking about the "txtErrorLabel"

```
<Window x:Class="BLVKServiceDashboard.Pages.ErrorWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ErrorWindow" Height="555" Width="420" Icon="/BLVKServiceDashboard;component/error.ico" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" ShowInTaskbar="False" Background="#FFEEEEEE" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid Margin="0,0,4,-3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.588,0.554">
    <Label Content="Fehlermeldungen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="25"/>

    <ListBox x:Name="lstErrorItems" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,58" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="500" Height="38" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="380"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Fehler: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="5,10,0,2" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtErrorLabel" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,10,0,2" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Meldungen löschen" Margin="147,514,147,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" Click="btnDelete_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.467,0.909"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textblock is in stackPanel which gives no boundary to your textBlock.

change parent to something which provides boundary to your textblock or set limits to stack panel itself.

TextWrapping will come into effect only when the textblock exceeds width of parent control. But stackPanel never imposes any boundary to its childs and hence all space is available.

a possible solution can be --

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="380"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Fehler: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="5,10,0,2" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtErrorLabel" 
                           Foreground="Black" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                           Margin="5,10,0,2" 
                           FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Mind sharing an example? I'm completely new to WPF and have honestly no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: added code, you can try other container controls to suit your requirement though